# Mbed LPC1768 Too Slow for Virtual Methods

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, efficiency, mbed

I've written an OOP program which calculates the position of an object following a Trapezoidal motion trajectory - accelerate up to max speed, coast until decel point, decelerate to target position.

The trajectory code is based around a state machine using virtual methods.

When I run the code on my Macbook, the program completes in a few seconds. On the mbed LPC1768 dev board, the program takes minutes to complete (far too long for my needs).

Is there anything in my code which could be slowing down the program? Should I upgrade to a more powerful chip? I'd really like to keep the OOP state machine if possible.

Perhaps somebody could also run the program on other mbed boards and see whether it completes in less time.

Comment: Well.. this is not a testing service. If you have performance issues, you should profile and optimize you program. And you definitely should take in account the HW limitations of you platform, such as  a lack of an FPU.

Comment: 1) Always post the relevant code on-site, not through links. 2) This is not a code review site; your question has nothing to do with electronics, it is a pure software question and should be posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest learning about your microcontroller.

- Cortex-M4F has single-precision FPU.
- Cortex-M4 has no FPU.
- Cortex-M3 also has no FPU.

Manipulating double-precision floating point numbers without FPU is horrendously slow.

Now, the question is, if the code is about fast double-precision FP performance, why did you select a micro without a double precision FPU? (or any FPU at all...)

(Note: I'm not aware of any micro with a double precision FPU).

**EDIT**

> @peufeu, Essentially, yes. The position will be compared with an encoder count, subjected to a PID loop and the result outputted to a DAC.

OK, so why not do just that? That's 1-2 pages of C code, maybe a tiny state machine... quite simple. No need for classes and Movers/Managers/Bloat. Implement your state machine using switch/case, obviously. "State" pattern has no place here.

> @peufeu, In what way am I abusing C++, if you don't mind me asking?

Why do it in one page of code when you can fill in a Mover class, one class for acceleration and deceleration and whatnot, and 13 source files?..... the result of which is you have no idea what the program is actually doing, and thus you wonder why it is slow.

The purpose of C++ is to have clear, readable code, which is also high-performance as the compiler can optimize it. If you want a dynamic language, use Python. If you want to turn a motor, use C.

Since a motor is slow by microcontroller standards, you can't possibly need more than, say, 1k updates/s on your PID. Using an ARM Cortex is fine, you can even use floats if you want... even without FPU and in software emulation...

I mean, a PIC16 can do it...

You can use float (or double) if you like safety, since your micro has plenty of power to spare.

Fixed point would only be useful performance-wise on a tiny micro. However it has other advantages, for example if you use a 32 bit value to encode your turns, with say 8 bits for the degrees from your encoder, then counting turns and doing modulos and stuff like that is very simple, but of course you got to guard against wrap around bugs.

Floating point allows you not to care about wraparound bugs.

> As-is? It seems to hide a few dozen lines of maths in a thousand lines of abstraction. There are apps written this way, e.g. Eclipse, but this style really only makes sense in huge componentised apps.

pj_50 -> Eeeeexactly, well said.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, it's not something I've ever thought about. Are you suggesting that I change my double types to, say, float? Looking at my code, is it clear then that this is the main cause for the lack of performance? I presume my virtual methods aren't an issue...? Thanks.

Comment: You might get a 50% speedup from double-> float, but really you want to consider integer or fixed point. Or doing it analytically ..

Comment: Precision is extremely important. Will fixed point give me similar precision to floating point?

Comment: Generally less precision. Really you want to profile it on the macbook and get execution time down to miliseconds. Also I'm still unclear on what the overall purpose is. How many iterations does it do.

Comment: You guys all forget the most important thing - *profiling*. Without it we are talking here about *premature optimization*.

Comment: @pjc50, The ultimate purpose is to control a motor. Iterations depends on target position/accel/max_speed. If the double is the issue here, I'm guessing I'll need to change the type, however C++ doesn't have a fixed point type. Off the top of your head, what is the simplest solution to this problem?

Comment: Okay, you can profile it ;) most likely result will be that FP-heavy code sucks hard without a FPU. Single precision should be plenty for a motor. Or fixed point. But the latter requires knowing what you're doing a little bit more...

Comment: "Precision is extremely important." - That's not a useful statement. What is the dynamic range of your variables, and what precision (exactly) do you require? If you specify those, you can then evaluate your process.

Comment: I think I'm way out of my depth here. The outputted position can simply be an integer, if that helps....?

Comment: I would also question the relevance of this huge C++ bloat for simple motor control...

Comment: @peufeu, Do you think a simple switch-statement would be more appropriate?

Comment: BTW, I might not understand something... but where are all of the calculations we are discussing here? I see some simple assignments here and there...

Comment: @Eugene, Accel, Flat and Decel.

Comment: That's what I am talking about. Few assignments and additions. Nothing extremely heavy

Comment: This looks like code written by Java developers. I mean, how many design patterns and nested OOP constructs do you need to turn a motor? We still don't know what you want to do. I suspect it is to swiftly move something from point A to point B while keeping acceleration and deceleration within certain design limits?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the code is very complex, as is often the case when C++ is abused so it is difficult to know how much number crunching the CPU actually does! (I'm pretty sure the task is simple though)

Comment: @peufeu, Essentially, yes. The position will be compared with an encoder count, subjected to a PID loop and the result outputted to a DAC.

Comment: @peufeu, In what way am I abusing C++, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: BTW, if you remove this `pc.printf` thing, I am pretty sure you will get amazed by the performance improvement...

Comment: @EugeneSh., I tried and the execution time was still way above what I expected.

Comment: @peufeu as an aside, some of ST's cortex m7 implementations have a double precision FPU, the  STM32F767NI for example.

Comment: Ok, so starting from scratch, what type do you recommend to store accel, position, etc? I'm guessing you're not too keen on the State design pattern - in truth I picked it because I was trying to make full use of OOP, which I've been learning. Perhaps I could use a simple switch statement, or simply contain everything in one function, with ifs...elses...?

Comment: OOP is usually a poor choice for embedded development. I basically agree with peufeu; the structure obscures the function to no useful purpose. Start by writing it all in one function then refactoring chunks out as the opportunity arises. Above all keep it simple.

Comment: Oh, and avoid memory allocation to the extent possible.

Comment: @pjc50, Aside from embedded development, would this code be useful/suitable in an application? I guess I'm asking whether you think it's actually good code, following correct practices, etc.
I'll re-write the code in the way you've suggested, however there is still the issue of which type to use. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: As-is? It seems to hide a few dozen lines of maths in a thousand lines of abstraction. There are apps written this way, e.g. Eclipse, but this style really only makes sense in huge componentised apps. Which type? Well, that depends on whether single-precision FP is fast or accurate enough for you. Fixed point is certainly a lot more work but likely to be ~10 times faster. But you've mentioned nothing about the expected range of the numbers or how many bits of precision you really need.

Comment: @pj50, Suppose single-precision is fast enough, how would this be implemented? Would the MCU need an FPU?

Comment: see edit to my answer

Comment: @peufeu, So it turns out it was indeed the printfs causing the slowness (as Eugene suggested), without which the program executes in mili-seconds. I will however follow your suggestions and re-write the code into 1 compact class. I'll upload my update as soon as I've completed it.